# Pause script , Step over and Step in to option are disabled in Chrome Dev. Tool in MAC

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I want to debug by JavaScript Application for that i have kept the

`debugger;` statement and in the VS code terminal i have typed node inspect by feature file path , i.e in below

```
node inspect ./bin/e2e --env stage --platform web --brand wdw --target local --version 21.06 --spec ./src/features/fastpass/book/book.resort.profile.feature
```

the code got stopped which is expected , and when i have opened the file in chrome dev tool the 'Pause script , Step over and Step in to option are disabled ' options are disabled , because of that i am not able to debug my file .

[image: Image of the debugger]

Comment: "_the code got stopped which is expected_" Why do you think that? Under the Scope and Call Stack panes it tells you "Not paused".

Comment: ok let me make clear it is getting stopped in VS code but not seeing any action in Dev tool window